# Submit form data within a table via Ajax always sends first row PHP

Tags: php, ajax, html

This table has many rows each with a few columns that are completed essentially as its own mini-form. The variable $y is auto-incremented and identifies which row should be submitted. My old form pre-ajax looked like this:

```
<tr>
    <form id='form$y' action=".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])." method='post''/>
    <input type='hidden' form='form$y' name='id' value='$id' />
    <td>
        <input style='height:18px' form='form$y' type='date' name='date value='$date'/>                                                                                                     
    </td>
    <td>    
        <select name='status' form='form$y' required/>
          <option>$status</option>
          <option value='option1'>option1</option>
          <option value='option2'>option2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input form='form$y' type='text' name='comment' value='$comment'/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  type='submit' value='Save' />
        </form> 
    </td>               
</tr>";
```

I've now tried to do the same thing via Ajax so that the page does not refresh upon submission and my code looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <form id='form$y' class='col-lg-3'/>
    <div class='form-group'>            
    <input type='hidden' name='id' class='form-control id' value='$id' />
    </div>  
    <td>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input style='height:18px' form='form$y' type='date' name='date' class='form-control date' value='$date' required/>                                                                                                     
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>    
        <div class='form-group'>
            <select name='status' form='form$y' required/>
              <option>$status</option>
              <option value='option1'>option1</option>
              <option value='option2'>option2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class='form-group'>
        <input form='form$y' type='text' name='comment' class='form-control comment' value='$comment'/>
            </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='button' form='form$y'  class='btn btn-default send' value='Submit'>
        </form> 
    </td>               
</tr>";
```

In the old form, it always worked correctly and the data from just that row in the table was submitted. In the new form, it always submits the data from the first row regardless of which row I press the 'submit' button on.

The Ajax is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function send_email(id,date,status,comment){
        $.post('post.php',{id:id,date:date,status:status,comment:comment}, function(data){
        if (data==='sent') {
            alert('sent');
        }else{
            alert('error');
        }


    });
    }


    $('.send').click(function(){
        var id = $('.id').val();
        var date = $('.date').val();
        var status = $('.status').val();
        var comment = $('.comment').val();
        send_email(id,date,status,comment);

    })


})
```

Is there a way to ensure that the value from the correct form is submitted? Does the form ID not work via Ajax? I cobbled together the Ajax from a few sources as I don't use it very often.

Comment: That is the working code, or you echo out the PHP variables?

Comment: The PHP variables are echoed out in the working code with the user submitted info.

Comment: Could you post your `post.php` code and is that the same as it was before the AJAX switch over?

Comment: post.php is actually the same page as the code is on. It is the same code as before.

Comment: Okay, well there's coding missing here so I'll just make a guess as to the issue.... you need to return the ID for the next record to your js and then have it update the field IDs in the DOM.

Comment: First of all you need to fix your broken HTML – you can not have a `form` as child of `tr` (and neither `div` or `input`). Either the `form` has to be around the complete `table` element, or inside a single `td` element.

Comment: @CBroe That could be but the structure of nesting the form within each tr worked fine before I attempted Ajax.

Comment: @chris85 I'm sure you're correct. The question is how do I submit just the ID for that row to the JS? It works fine without Ajax by defining the form ID, how can I do it with Ajax? Thanks.

Comment: Don't echo 'sent' from your PHP file; send back the new ID then `data` will have it and you can have the JS update the DOM so your next submission will be at the right value.

Comment: @Chris85 I'm sorry, but I don't understand. 'sent' is not being echoed anywhere. I'm unsure how to send the new ID.

Comment: You wrote the JS? You have `if (data==='sent')` which should be checking the return from your ajax request. See the doc for the function you're using. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: $Chris85. I'm not sure I'm explaining the problem properly. The page has for example 100 rows. At the end of each row is a 'submit' button. When I don't use Ajax it correctly submits just the data from that row. When I do use Ajax, it submits the data from the top row which is incorrect.  The problem seems to be that with Ajax it is not recognizing the form as being from just that row.